# Xaml layout, box to the left corner over another box

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get to this layout.

[image: Layout]

I got the red part correct but I am not able to position green box on top of the left part of the red box.

Green box needs to have same width as left part of the red part.
Green box has to be on the view from top to bottom.

This is my code so far. I am absolute xaml beginner so I have no clue if its even possible to do this kind of layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="HOT_App.Views.ItemsPage"
              Title="{Binding Title}"
             x:Name="BrowseItemsPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="80"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="red" Grid.Row="0"></BoxView>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="red" Grid.Column="1"></BoxView>
            <BoxView WidthRequest="300" BackgroundColor="green" Grid.Row="1"></BoxView>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="Aqua" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></BoxView>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `RowSpan` to make an element span multiple rows

```
<BoxView BackgroundColor="green" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
```

Comment: This will create only one element in the left top corner no ? I need both elements. Red in the back and green on top of it.

Comment: Yes, leave your other elements as-is.  But you will need to adjust the size of the green if you want the red to be visible behind it.

Comment: Coool, This works. :) Only one thing is missing. How do I make green and cyan box to be on whole screen ? I tried Heigh="*" on row definition but that does not work.

Comment: you need to make your Grid fill the screen - use FillAndExpand for Horizontal and Vertical Options.  And get rid of the StackLayout, it is doing nothing